# Reformat tables

Tags: bash, shell, table

I have some tables (`table.txt`) that have been wrongly built and present redundancey in the results, as follow:

```
YEAR MONTH DAY RES
1971 1     1   245
1971 1     2   587
...
1971 12    31  685
1971 1     1   245
1971 1     2   587
...
1971 12    31  685
1972 1     1   549
1972 1     2   746
...
```

Instead I would like to have:

```
YEAR MONTH DAY RES
1971 1     1   245
1971 1     2   587
...
1971 12    31  685
1972 1     1   549
1972 1     2   746
...
```

So the problem is that the results are presented twice in the table. That means (with the provided example) that after the '1971' I should expected year '1972' and not '1971' again. Is there a way to delete the redundant results using sh/bash?

I have to notice that my data run throughout 1971 until 2099 day by day, and that they have exactly the same format even after year 2000, as follow:

```
YEAR MONTH DAY RES
1971 1     1   245
1971 1     2   587
...
2000 1     1   875
2000 1     2   456
...
2099 12    31  321
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two mutually exclusive `sed` loops:

```
sed -ne'p;/ 12 * 31 /!d;:n' -e'n;//!bn' <<""
YEAR MONTH DAY RES
1971 1     1   245
1971 1     2   587
...
1971 12    31  685
1971 1     1   245
1971 1     2   587
...
1971 12    31  685
1972 1     1   549
1972 1     2   746
...
1972 12    31  999
1972 1     1   933
1972 1     2   837
...
1972 12    31  343
```

---

```
YEAR MONTH DAY RES
1971 1     1   245
1971 1     2   587
...
1971 12    31  685
1972 1     1   549
1972 1     2   746
...
1972 12    31  999
```

Basically `sed` has two states - `p`rint and *eat*. In the first state - the `p`rint state - `sed` automatically `p`rints every input line then checks it against the `/ 12 * 31 /` pattern. If the current pattern space does `!` not match it is `d`eleted and `sed` pulls in the next input line and starts the script again from the top - at the `p`rint command without attempting to run anything that follows the `d`elete command at all.

When an input line *does* match `/ 12 * 31 /`, however, `sed` falls through to the second half of the script - the *eat* loop. First it defines a branch `:` label named `n`; then it overwrites the current pattern space with the `n`ext input line, and then it compares the current pattern space to the `//` last matched pattern. Because the line that matched it before has just been overwritten with the `n`ext one, the first iteration of this *eat* loop doesn't match, and every time it does `!` not `sed` `b`ranches back to the `:n` label to get the `n`ext input line and once again compare it to the `//` last matched pattern.

When another match is finally made - some 365 `n`ext lines later - `sed` does `-n`ot automatically print it when it completes its script, pulls in the next input line, and starts again from the top at the `p`rint command in its first state. So each loop state will fall through to the next on the same key and do as little as possible in the meantime to find the next key.

Note that the entire script completes without invoking a single editing routine, and that it needs only to compile the single regexp. The automaton that results is very simple - it understands only `[123 ]` and `[^123 ]`. What's more, at least half of the comparisons will very likely be made without any compilations, because the only address referenced in the *eat* loop at all is the `//` empty one. `sed` can therefore complete that loop entirely with a single `regexec()` call per input line. `sed` *may* do similar for the `p`rint loop as well.

---

#### timed

---

I was curious about how the various answers here might perform, and so I came up with my own table:

```
dash <<""
    d=0 D=31 IFS=: set 1970 1
    while   case  "$*:${d#$D}" in (*[!:]) ;;
            ($(($1^($1%4)|(d=0))):1:)
                     D=29 set $1 2;;
            (*:1:)   D=28 set $1 2;;
            (*[3580]:)
                     D=30 set $1 $(($2+1));;
            (*:)     D=31 set $(($1+!(t<730||(t=0)))) $(($2%12+1))
            esac
    do      printf  '%-6d%-4d%-4d%d\n' "$@" $((d+=1)) $((t+=1))
    done|   head    -n1000054 >/tmp/dates
```

---

```
dash <<<''  6.62s user 6.95s system 166% cpu 8.156 total
```

That puts a million+ lines in `/tmp/dates` and doubles the output for each of years 1970 - 3338. The file looks like:

```sh
tail -n1465 </tmp/dates | head; echo; tail </tmp/dates
```

---

```
3336  12  27  728
3336  12  28  729
3336  12  29  730
3336  12  30  731
3336  12  31  732
3337  1   1   1
3337  1   2   2
3337  1   3   3
3337  1   4   4
3337  1   5   5

3338  12  22  721
3338  12  23  722
3338  12  24  723
3338  12  25  724
3338  12  26  725
3338  12  27  726
3338  12  28  727
3338  12  29  728
3338  12  30  729
3338  12  31  730
```

...some of it anyway.

And then I tried the different commands on it:

```sh
for  cmd in "sort -uVk1,3" \
            "sed -ne'p;/ 12 * 31 /!d;:n' -e'n;//!bn'" \
            "awk '"'{u=$1 $2 $3 $4;if (!a[u]++) print;}'\'
do   eval   "time ($cmd|wc -l)" </tmp/dates
done
```

---

```
500027
( sort -uVk1,3 | wc -l; ) \
1.85s user 0.11s system 280% cpu 0.698 total

500027
( sed -ne'p;/ 12 * 31 /!d;:n' -e'n;//!bn' | wc -l; ) \
0.64s user 0.09s system 110% cpu 0.659 total

500027
( awk '{u=$1 $2 $3 $4;if (!a[u]++) print;}' | wc -l; ) \
1.46s user 0.15s system 104% cpu 1.536 total
```

The `sort` and `sed` commands both completed in less than half the time `awk` did - and these results were typical. I did run them several times. It appears all of the commands are writing out the correct number of lines as well - and so they probably all work.

`sort` and `sed` were fairly well neck and neck - with `sed` generally a hair ahead - for completion time for every run, but `sort` does more actual work to achieve its results than either of the other two commands. It is running parallel jobs to complete its task and benefits a great deal from my multi-core cpu. `awk` and `sed` both peg the single-core assigned them for the entire time they process.

The results here are from a standard, up-to-date GNU `sed`, but I did try another. In fact, I tried all three commands with other binaries, but only the `sed` command actually worked with my heirloom tools. The others, as I guess due to non-standard syntax, simply quit with error before getting off the ground.

It is good to use standard syntax when possible - you can freely use more simple, honed, and efficient implementations in many cases that way:

```sh
PATH=/usr/heirloom/bin/posix2001:$PATH; time ...
```

---

```
500027
( sed -ne'p;/ 12 * 31 /!d;:n' -e'n;//!bn' | wc -l; ) \
0.31s user 0.12s system 136% cpu 0.318 total
```

Comment: @ mikeserv - I might sound stupid, but where do I put my input file in that command?

Comment: @steve - The `<<""` heredoc serves as input. So just drop everything to the right and below `<<""` and you can `<infile >outfile` instead.

Answer (score 3):

try to pipe it to awk

```
awk '!a[$0]++' files.txt > new_files.txt
mv new_files.txt files.txt
```

this will output line only once.

edit: (not sure concatenating var will do the trick)

```
awk '{u=$1 $2 $3 $4 ; if ( !a[u]++ ) print ; } ' ...
```

Comment: @ Archemar - It works, but somehow after year '2000' it´s no longer working. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: there was a well know 2K bug :-) can you provide some sample of those lines ?

Comment: @ Archemar - Yes I will re-edit my question accordingly to the 2k bug :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$ (head -1 table.txt ; tail -n +2 table.txt | sort -u -V -k1,3)
YEAR MONTH DAY RES
1971 1     1   245
1971 1     2   587
1971 2     1   587
1971 12    31  685
1972 1     1   549
1972 1     2   746
2000 1     1   875
2000 1     2   456
2099 12    31  321
```

Comment: I'd use version sort `-uV`

Comment: @ cas - It seems to work but then the data are anymore chronologically organised, do you have any idea why?

Comment: You probably want to use the `-n` option to `sort`, otherwise `1971 2    1` will come after `1971 12    31`.

Comment: @steve - preserve the original order first: `nl -w1 <infile | sort -u -k2,4 | sort -nk1,1 | cut -f2-`. the order is *not* preserved because the `sort` is *not* numeric really at all - all three included fields are merged and all of the comparisons made are basic dictionary ones.

Comment: @NateEldredge - you cant merge all of those keys *and* do a `-n`umeric `sort`. `sort`'s `-n`umeric mode compares only up to the first non-numeric character in the compared columns - and there are three merged here. `printf 1971%\ d%\ d\\n 4 15 12 31 1 2 12 30| sort -unk1,3` prints only `1971 4 15`.

Comment: @costas, yep. version sort works. numeric sort doesn't. updated answer.